# How to run command on a another open cmd from a command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-line-interface

I am executing my bat file, that will execute the certain commands and opens a new Command prompt, then I need to run few command on a newly opened cmd prompt.But how i can do it?

What i am doing in my bat file is below -

```
cd C:/someFolder
start application.exe
ls
```

Currently it opens the new cmd but executes ls in the old cmd only

Comment: `.bat` files are specific to Windows (and DOS). On Linux (and Unix flavors) usually runs shell scripts. The Windows `cmd` interpreter is not Linux or Unix. Please narrow down your question. It can be done, but how exactly depends on what you're actually doing.

Comment: `ls` is not a built in command in Windows cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create another batch file, that contains all the commands you want to run "in the other (console) window". Than start this one with `start`.

For example, to start the commands `c1.exe` and `c2.exe` in other console window, create the following batch file, `other.cmd`:

```
@echo off
c1.exe
c2.exe
```

Then launch that via `start`:

```
rem commands in this console window
start other.cmd
rem again, commands in this console window
```

A view things to remember:

- Commands in the `other.cmd` batch file will run one after another (in the other window).
- Commands in the current window continue running, unless you use `start` with the `/wait` option.
- The "other window" runs a completely distinct console session (including current directory, environment variables, etc.)

It might be beneficial if you explain *why* you need to run the commands like you say you want to. Maybe there is a better (or more robust) solution than the above.